# How can I set up an automatic authentication layer in nginx?

Tags: authentication, nginx

I'm building an ecosystem of applications under a common domain, with each application under a separate subdomain.  I have built an authentication application for the ecosystem, but it requires each other application to be specially configured to use it.  Is there a way to configure nginx to manage user sessions, possibly forwarding user information as headers to the various applications?

Comment: Cookies are (sub)domain specific and don't transfer to anohter sub(domain). Perhaps your question is about getting access between internal services?

Comment: I'll have a series of customer-facing applications under a variety of subdomains and potentially written in a variety of server-side languages.  Currently I have an OAuth2 provider set up to manage authentication, but implementing the client-side portion of that in each new application is tedious, especially in situations where I'd like to just toss some static files up but still need to protect them.

Comment: did you have a chance to review the answers below?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me show you a common pattern for cross-application authentications you can use with Nginx:

1) Build standalone service called auth_service, work independently from the web applications as required

2) Each subdomain apps will have an individual location that proxies to the same authentication service

```
location = /auth {
  proxy_pass http://auth_service.localhost/authenticate;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

3) Individual web app uses "/auth" location to pass login/pass (based on POST data, headers or temporary tokens)

4) Standalone service's handler "/authenticate" accepts web apps login/pass  and returns 200 or 401 if failed

The root of this approach is "/auth" location sits on each own subdomain based application,
the server side dispatches the call to the single authentication end point which can be re-used efficiently and you can avoid code duplication.

This module [Auth Request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) is not build by default, but comes with source code. Before use just compile Nginx with --with-http_auth_request_module option.

UPDATE: Since Nginx 1.5.4 this plugin comes in standard distribution without require to compile it in separately.

Comment: This may be close enough to meet my needs.  Since it would proxy to an existing auth application seems like it would work for just about any application.  Since each application would still have to manage its session separately that wouldn't necessarily be ideal, but it's starting to look like the only way to manage that would be to write a new nginx module capable of doing its own session management.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a custom module which gets data from a database based on who logged in, this way you manage from a central point and can set whatever you want based on whatever is in the database, from the other side you synchronize the database with authentication sources.

A client always has the same login interface, nginx always communicates with the same authentication source in the same way, you only need to manage the database and its interfaces to the authentication sources.

client <> nginx <> database <> set values where client is going and is allowed to do.